# trying to figure out how authentication is performed in this example

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at some example code and can't figure out how authentication is done.

Any ideas how this simple code authenticates users?

Thanks,

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
      window._auth_token_name = "authenticity_token";
      window._auth_token = "k0d6elNSSvaejR63eiqcZrv3O8fU/6VL2kvoqmpdO6k=";

    //]]>
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="messages">
      <div id="info"></div>
      <div id="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">


</div>
    <div id="center">
      <table>
  <form action="/admin/login" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="k0d6elNSSvaejR63eiqcZrv3O8fU/6VL2kvoqmpdO6k=" /></div>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><input id="user_username" name="user[username]" size="30" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log in" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that simple code does not authenticate anything, It's simply a html page with a form to submit. The authentication process takes place on a server at this route: `/admin/login`

the server could be anything.. php, ruby on rails etc

Answer (score 0):

The authentication is done on the server side in the code that responds to the action admin/login. The authenticity you see on the page is to prevent cross site scripting and is in no way connected to the login.